# EJB delpoy error

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jboss, ejb

I want to deploy my war archive on JBoss, but I got this error :

```
    11:26:08,539 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."lab4-war.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."lab4-war.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "lab4-war.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'pro.alexfly.lab4.dao.UserDAO' for binding pro.alexfly.lab4.controller.AdminPanelController/userDAO
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:215)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:145)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

I try to google it and fix it on the same error solutions in Internet, but I could not fix it. I get this error more and more.

My DAO interface :

```
/**
 * @Author is flystyle
 * Created on 05.06.16.
 */
public interface IRequestDAO {
    Integer createRequest(final Request source);
    List<Request> list(final Date date);
    List<Request> list();
    List<Request> list(final Station begin, final Station end);
    Request getRequestById (final int id);
    List<Request> getRequestsByUserId (final int userId);

    void removeRequestById(final int id);
    void removeRequestByUser(final User user);

    @Deprecated
    void removeAllRequests();

}
```

My UserDAO class :

```
@Stateless // look I have this annootation!
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public User verifyEnter(String name, String pass) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        tr = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM rails_user WHERE user_name = :an AND user_pass = :ap";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(User.class);
        query.setParameter("an", name);
        query.setParameter("ap", pass);
        User res = (User) query.uniqueResult();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        return res;
    }

    public Admin adminEnter(String name, String pass) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        tr = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM rails_admin WHERE admin_name = :an AND admin_pass = :ap";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(Admin.class);
        query.setParameter("an", name);
        query.setParameter("ap", pass);
        Admin res = (Admin) query.uniqueResult();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        return res;
    }

    public Integer register(String name, String surname, String pass) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setSurname(surname);
        user.setPass(pass);
        Integer id = (Integer) session.save(user);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public List getAllUsers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        tr = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM rails_user";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(User.class);
        List res = query.list();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        return res;
    }

    public User getUserById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        tr = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM rails_user WHERE user_id = :id";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(User.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        User res = (User) query.uniqueResult();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        return res;
    }

    public void banUser(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM rails_user WHERE request_id = :id");
        q.addEntity(User.class);
        q.setParameter("id", id);
        q.executeUpdate();
    }

    public boolean verifyAdminEnter(String name, String pass) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        tr = session.beginTransaction();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM rails_admin WHERE admin_name = :an AND admin_pass = :ap";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(Admin.class);
        query.setParameter("an", name);
        query.setParameter("ap", pass);
        Admin res = (Admin) query.uniqueResult();
        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        if (res.getName().equals(name) && res.getPass().equals(pass))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

My Admin Controller class :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "rails_admin_panel")
@SessionScoped
public class AdminPanelController implements AdminAction{

    private List<User> allUsers;
    private List<Request> allRequests;

    @EJB
    private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    @EJB
    private RequestDAO requestDAO = new RequestDAO();

    public void viewAllUsers() {
        allUsers = userDAO.getAllUsers();
    }

    public void viewAllRequests() {
        allRequests = requestDAO.list();
    }

    public void deleteRequest(int id) {
        requestDAO.removeRequestById(id);
    }

    public void deleteUser(int id) {
        userDAO.banUser(id);
    }

    public List<Request> getAllRequests() {
        return allRequests;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return allUsers;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

P.S.  [War Packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrvd.png)

Comment: seems like some of your dependent libraries are missing on server. Ensure they are available for your ejb when the server starts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During start app server cannot find interface `pro.alexfly.lab4.dao.UserDAO` because you have no one. To fix it:

- Try to use you interface `IUserDAO` here:

> ```
> @EJB
> private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
> ```

- Do not create your own instance manually, it should be injected by JBoss container.
- Check that your interfaces have `@Local` annotation.